# Iterate through array via ngRepeat with breaks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need your help.
I decided to make an attempt to create some kind of online market and I am somehow new to some parts of AngularJS and this is first time when I faced such a problem with ng-repeat.
I have the following html-structure (it is only a required part of it):

```
<div class="goods">
    <div class="goods-row" ng-repeat="???">
        <div class="good" ng-repeat="???">
            <button id="add_to_cart">+</button>
            <div class="descr">
                <div class="descr-top">
                    <h5 class="g-name">
                        NAME IS HERE
                    </h5>
                    <span class="g-price">
                        PRICE IS HERE
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="descr-mid" ng-bind="good.description"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"Goods"(goods-class) includes "rows of goods"(goods-row). Every row should include (by default) 4 goods (good-class), but, it should be also noticed that I will use filter, that could change number of visible goods in a row, because of that I need a flexible solution.
What should I enter in ng-repeat?
P.S. I created a blueprint with JS-code (posted below), that somehow shows what I want, but how to make it in AngularJS?

```
var arr = [];
for (i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) {
   arr.push({
      number: i
   });
}
var divider = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    for (var j = 0; j < divider; j++) {
        if ((j + i) < arr.length) {
           console.log(arr[j + i]);
        }
    }
    i = i + divider;
    console.log(" ");
}
```

Comment: Instead of logging the values in your blueprint, create the structure needed by the view (i.e. an array of rows, each row being an array of 4 goods), and iterate over that structure.

Comment: In blueprint main part is a for-loops, no matter how I create an array. I've already thought of it, but after filtering I could see lots of rows with 2 or 3 lements instead of their re-structure in new rows with elements that suits filter's parameters.
If there would be no answer I could just disable all goods that does not suit the filter, without making them disappear

Comment: I want to find some kind of solution, in which, after applying a filter (for example price), all rows will be restructured into new ones, that would also contain max 4 elements, that suit filter params

Comment: Well, apply the filter first, and construct the structure after, with the values returned by the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library you can use `chunk` function to split an array into chunks and then build a list that suits your needs.

So basically just iterate as you would do for a normal list of arrays (which represent your rows containing goods) and implement a function that build this list according to the divider. That way you can invoke the function when you need to rebuild your list (on keyup of the input in the example bellow) and let AngularJS do the rest.

```js
(function(angular) {

  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('ngRepeat', [])
    .controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  
      // the goods
      $scope.goods = [
        { name: "name-1", price: 1.01, description: 'desc-1' }, 
        { name: "name-2", price: 2.02, description: 'desc-2' },
        { name: "name-3", price: 3.03, description: 'desc-3' },
        { name: "name-4", price: 4.04, description: 'desc-4' },
        { name: "name-5", price: 5.05, description: 'desc-5' },
        { name: "name-6", price: 6.06, description: 'desc-6' },
        { name: "name-7", price: 7.07, description: 'desc-7' },
        { name: "name-8", price: 8.08, description: 'desc-8' },
        { name: "name-9", price: 9.09, description: 'desc-9' },
        { name: "name-10", price: 10.10, description: 'desc-10' },
        { name: "name-11", price: 11.11, description: 'desc-11' },
        { name: "name-12", price: 12.12, description: 'desc-12' }
      ];

      // divider determines how many goods per row (defaulted to 4)
      $scope.divider = 4;
    
      // function that build the rows of goods
      $scope.dividerChanged = function() {
        $scope.rows = _.chunk($scope.goods, $scope.divider);
      };
    
      // initialize rows on first load
      $scope.dividerChanged();
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```css
.divider {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
  
.goods-row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.good {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
    
    divider: <input type="text" ng-model="divider" ng-keyup="dividerChanged()" class="divider">
    
    <div class="goods">
      <div class="goods-row" ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class="good" ng-repeat="good in row">
          <button id="add_to_cart">+</button>
          <div class="descr">
            <div class="descr-top">
              <h5 class="g-name">{{ good.name }}</h5>
              <span class="g-price">{{ good.price | currency }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="descr-mid">{{ good.description }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, it seems more flexible than just manual dividing on array of arrays, and I think, that I will be able to trigger re-structure of rows on keyup, so that elements that will pass a filter-test (for example, those whose price is more than 100) will be used to form new rows

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand your question, are you trying to build a filtered array but always want to display the top 4 entries?

If yes, then it can be done with `ng-repeat` filter (custom or not) and `limitTo` filter

`<div ng-repeat="data in test.data | customFilter:test.selectedFilter | limitTo:4">{{data}}</div>`

https://jsbin.com/wajapabaro/1/edit?html,js,output